# jQuery Load Script Once onClick

Tags: jquery, load, click, onclick

I am trying to load 2 scripts in jquery only once a #element is clicked. Currently, I am trying to use:

```
    jQuery("#element").click(function () {
       jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script.js');
       jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script2.js');
    });
```

The problem is that the scripts load everytime the #element is clicked. I only want the scripts to load once - and currently they also make like this

```
"http://127.0.0.1/pck/Js/jquery.script.js?_=1279101767931"
```

How can I load the scripts ONLY once and stop the non-cache. I am using ASP.NET MVC ?

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) like this:

```
jQuery("#element").one('click', function () {
   jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script.js?' + (new Date().getTime()));
   jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script2.js?"' + (new Date().getTime()));
});
```

[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) executes the event handler exactly once, the `Date()` piece is for the cache.  I'm no sure you want [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) though, if your intent is just to get/execute the scripts, then [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is more appropriate, like this:

```
jQuery("#element").one('click', function () {
   jQuery.getScript('/js/jquery.script.js');
   jQuery.getScript('/js/jquery.script2.js');
});
```

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) requests of `dataType = "script"` (which [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is) [won't be cached](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L265).

---

If you **want to cache**, you have two options, you can use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) once (but this affects *all* subsequent [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) calls):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Or make the full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call version that [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is short for:

```
jQuery("#element").one('click', function () {
   jQuery.ajax({ url: '/js/jquery.script.js', dataType: 'json', cache: true });
   jQuery.ajax({ url: '/js/jquery.script2.js', dataType: 'json', cache: true });
});
```

Comment: ok cool thx so much ill give this a try now :) can I just replace the .load with .getscript ? also I want the scripts to cache. current they add the ?_=2312312312 but I don't want them too ?

Comment: @Tom - Yup, I added an example...if you look at your console, getscript will add the time to the querystring under the covers, it happens here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L269

Comment: @Tom - They need to add that...that's *how* they instruct the browser not to cache, otherwise IE in particular will hold onto them.

Comment: @Nick Craver: +1 for that caching thing, noobs run into problems as they don't know requests being cached in those cases.

Comment: hey thanks so much nick - if I want to cache the scripts ? can I do this with the above code ? i.e. currently the ?=2312312 is added but I would prefer they were cached ?

Comment: @Tom - I *completely* misread that, you *want* to cache, one moment.

Comment: I like the idea of examples of cached and not, gives flexibility.

Comment: ah ok great thx. the only problem I thougt is I would have to use EncodeString() or something like this :)

Comment: @Tom - I added how to fetch them *without* that timestamp for caching as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
  jQuery("#element").click(function () {
       jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script.js');
       jQuery('#elementcontainer').load('/js/jquery.script2.js');
       jQuery(this).unbind('click');
    });
```

Note the `unbind()` method called on `$(this)` (which is the element `#element`). You can check more `unbind()` functionality [here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).